# Storing user data in one big database or in a different file for each user - which is more efficient?

Tags: python, json, database, performance, security

I'm trying to store user data for a website in Python I'm making. Which is more efficient:

-Storing all the user data in one huge table
-Storing all the user data in several tables, one per user, in one database. 
-Storing each user's data in a XML or JSON file, one file per user. Each file has a unique name based on the user id.

Also, which is safer? I'm biased towards storing user data in JSON files because that is something I already know how to do.

Any advice? I'd post some code I already have, but this is more theoretical than code-based.

Comment: This question is so general it can't really be answered,, the use case is really vague.. There is a reason that "most" sites use SQL databases with normal database structure.. It is proven and works for most cases. You have not defined any real reason to deviate...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think efficiency should be part of your calculus.

I don't like either of your proposed designs.

One table?  That's not normalized.  I don't know what data you're talking about, but you should know about normalization.

Multiple copies?  That's not scalable.  Every time you add a user you add a table?  Sounds like the perfect way to ensure that your user population will be small.

Is all the data JSON?  Document based?  Maybe you should consider a NoSQL document based solution like MongoDB.

Comment: MongoDB looks great for storing user settings and preferences- but would I be wrong or making a mistake if I stored usernames and passwords with it as well?

Comment: I have no idea.  I don't know all your data.  You said JSON.  I thought MongoDB.